# GNU LD fill empty linker section

Tags: c, gcc, linker, binutils

I'm writing bare-metal code for a microcontroller (MSP430 series) using the GCC/binutils toolchain and I'd like to use my linker script to fill unused interrupt vectors with the "loop forever" opcode (in dev, in production the "SW reset" opcode). I can't seem to make this happen.

Here's my linker script (or the relevant sections):

```
MEMORY {
  SFR              : ORIGIN = 0x0000, LENGTH = 0x0010 /* END=0x0010, size 16 */
  PERIPHERAL_8BIT  : ORIGIN = 0x0010, LENGTH = 0x00F0 /* END=0x0100, size 240 */
  PERIPHERAL_16BIT : ORIGIN = 0x0100, LENGTH = 0x0100 /* END=0x0200, size 256 */
  RAM              : ORIGIN = 0x1C00, LENGTH = 0x0800 /* END=0x23FF, size 2048 */
  INFOMEM          : ORIGIN = 0x1800, LENGTH = 0x0200 /* END=0x19FF, size 512 as 4 128-byte segments */
  INFOA            : ORIGIN = 0x1980, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x19FF, size 128 */
  INFOB            : ORIGIN = 0x1900, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x197F, size 128 */
  INFOC            : ORIGIN = 0x1880, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x18FF, size 128 */
  INFOD            : ORIGIN = 0x1800, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x187F, size 128 */
  FRAM (rxw)       : ORIGIN = 0x4400, LENGTH = 0xBB80 /* END=0xFF7F, size 48000 */
  VECT1            : ORIGIN = 0xFF90, LENGTH = 0x0002
  VECT2            : ORIGIN = 0xFF92, LENGTH = 0x0002
  VECT3            : ORIGIN = 0xFF94, LENGTH = 0x0002
  ... snip ...
  VECT54           : ORIGIN = 0xFFFA, LENGTH = 0x0002
  VECT55           : ORIGIN = 0xFFFC, LENGTH = 0x0002
  RESETVEC         : ORIGIN = 0xFFFE, LENGTH = 0x0002
  BSL              : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x0800
  HIFRAM (rxw)     : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 0x00003FFF
}

SECTIONS
{
  __interrupt_vector_1   : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_1 )) } > VECT1 =0x3C00
  __interrupt_vector_2   : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_2 )) } > VECT2 =0x3C00
  __interrupt_vector_3   : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_3 )) } > VECT3 =0x3C00
  __interrupt_vector_4   : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_4 )) } > VECT4 =0x3C00
  __interrupt_vector_5   : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_5 )) } > VECT5 =0x3C00
  __interrupt_vector_6   : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_6 )) } > VECT6 =0x3C00
  ... snip ...
  __interrupt_vector_52  : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_52)) KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_timer0_b0)) } > VECT52 =0x3C00
  __interrupt_vector_53  : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_53)) KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_comp_e)) } > VECT53 =0x3C00
  __interrupt_vector_54  : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_54)) KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_unmi)) } > VECT54 =0x3C00
  __interrupt_vector_55  : { KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_55)) KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_sysnmi)) } > VECT55 =0x3C00
  __reset_vector :
  {
    KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_56))
    KEEP (*(__interrupt_vector_reset))
    KEEP (*(.resetvec))
  } > RESETVEC
... and all the usual stuff, .data, .bss, etc ...
```

(0x3C00 is the "jump forever" opcode)

This doesn't seem to produce the sections at all if there's not at least one symbol on the input.

I tried messing around with . = .; and similar commands to get the section to be created even when there's nothing in the input sections, which sometimes worked, but I need the sections generated to be type PROGBITS and have the A flag set, otherwise they won't be loaded to the target. None of my attempts managed to produce this configuration.

What can I do to generate a section filled with 0x3C00, which is type PROGBITS and has the A flag set, when there is nothing in the input sections?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the SHORT(0x3C00) syntax?

```
__interrupt_vector_1 : { SHORT(0x3C00) } > VECT1
```

This tells the linker to put two bytes 0x3C,00 into the section named `__interrupt_vector_1` which is allocated in memory region `VECT1`. I don't think you need the `KEEP` directive anymore either. The name of the section, if not used, can be anything you want too. I usually match my sections to my memory regions in cases like this, e.g.

```
.vect1 : { SHORT(0x3C00) } >vect1
```

note the dot on the section name.

Also your `VECT1` should be:

```
VECT1         (x) : ORIGIN = 0xFF90, LENGTH = 0x0002
```

Because it's executable code.